# Стоит ли кодить весь сайт на jsx(react)

Tags: reactjs, jsx, create-react-app

Есть сайт, на котором 20% компонентов React и 80% обычного html контента. Html разметка средней сложности, возможно с новыми html5 тегами с редкими атрибутами. Именно этого я и боюсь, что JSX не полностью поддерживает HTML5, и при усложнении сайта, соблюдая семантику, начнутся проблемы. Используя create-react-app стоит ли создавать ВЕСЬ сайт используя JSX? Все таки это удобно - единая архитектура, даже там где не нужны методы и данные из родителей. Кто-то сталкивался с проблемным JSX для определенных html элементов?

Answer (score 0):

**JSX** полностью обратно-совместим с **HTML5**.

Поэтому никаких проблем не возникнет если переписать всё на JSX.